# Where at memory are my variables stored in C?

Tags: c, variables

By considering that the memory is divided into four segments: data, heap, stack, and code, where do global variables, static variables, constant data types, local variables (defined and declared in functions), variables (in main function), pointers, and dynamically allocated space (using malloc and calloc) get stored in memory?

I think they would be allocated as follows:

```
Global variables -------> data
Static variables -------> data
Constant data types -----> code
Local variables (declared and defined in functions) --------> stack
Variables declared and defined in main function -----> heap
Pointers (for example, char *arr, int *arr) -------> heap
Dynamically allocated space (using malloc and calloc) -------->
```

stack
I am referring to these variables only from the C perspective.

Please correct me if I am wrong as I am new to C.

Comment: PEP8 suggests Python. Why do you have the JS tag? You also have a tag about environment variables (which are defined outside an application) - why?

Comment: I would think a value that cannot be stored in a variable is sort of useless.

Comment: Everything in Python is an object, and all objects can be stored in global variables.
While I'm uncertain, I think this also applies to variables within classes.

Comment: Does someone know some value that is not allowed? yes, try to store pi in a variable.

Comment: Something you can't store in a variable: `max(itertools.count())`.

Comment: @RoytmanPiccoli it's *two different languages*. You cannot reasonably expect that all programming languages follow the same rules. If you did, you'd have tagged way more than two (which is also wrong). Questions need to be *specific*. Unless you ask for something which is language agnostic and this isn't it.

Comment: Because it never finishes.

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki such a value doesn't exist in a programming language, thus it's not an exception. You cannot assign something that doesn't exist to a variable.

Comment: @Pychopath also not a value. You similarly cannot store an application crash. Because it's not a value.

Comment: @VLAZ You'll never see that crashing.

Comment: @Pychopath yet it will not produce a value. Which is my point. A crash is *also* a thing that is not a value.

Comment: A crash does not produce a value since it is never evaluated, and hence it cannot occur in any program as an expression. However, this is not a value, so it falls outside the scope of the question. I'll write an answer.

Comment: @VLAZ Oh, I missed the word "similarly". Anyway... it's a joke. I think the question doesn't really make sense, so some joke answers is all there can be.

Answer (score 1):

As everything in Python is an object, and all objects can be assigned to variables, one cannot create a non-erroring value that cannot be assigned to a variable.

However, as an aside, there exist expressions that can never be assigned to a variable. One would think expressions that throw errors fall within this box, such as `1/0`, which throws ZeroDivisionError:

```
>>> foo=1/0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#33>", line 1, in <module>
    foo=1/0
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
```

but in fact those expressions can be caught within try/except statements, such as the one below:

```
try:
  foo=1/0
except:
  pass
```

This is not the end of the story however, since there exist expressions which cause the Python interpreter to segfault. The shortest one that I'm aware of is from Codegolf Stack Exchange:

```
exec((lambda:0).__code__.replace(co_consts=()))
```

Which will always crash the python interpreter, even within a try-except statement.

Comment: could remove your answer I want to remove this question I can`t cos have your answer.

Comment: Why do you wish to remove this question?

Comment: Because this site just accept nice questions and "Closed. This question needs details or clarity. It is not currently accepting answers."